# vsftpd server with EFS mount - root device getting full

Tags: ubuntu, mount

Another question I couldn't find Google answer for

I have a FTP server with vsftpd, where I mounted AWS EFS drive under /mnt/
all the user directories are under

```
/mnt/efs/fs1/
             user1/
             user2/
             ...etc
```

When users upload files, i can see using  `df -hT` command that `/dev/root` is getting full. Is there a way to mount EFS drive as a separate drive, or under directory that would not blow the `/dev/root` space up?

I mount the EFS volume using user data

```
#cloud-config
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
runcmd:
- yum install -y amazon-efs-utils
- apt-get -y install amazon-efs-utils
- yum install -y nfs-utils
- apt-get -y install nfs-common
- file_system_id_1=fs-efs-id-here
- efs_mount_point_1=/mnt/efs/fs1
- mkdir -p "${efs_mount_point_1}"
- test -f "/sbin/mount.efs" && printf "\n${file_system_id_1}:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} efs tls,_netdev\n" >> /etc/fstab || printf "\n${file_system_id_1}.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport,_netdev 0 0\n" >> /etc/fstab
- test -f "/sbin/mount.efs" && grep -ozP 'client-info]\nsource' '/etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf'; if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then printf "\n[client-info]\nsource=liw\n" >> /etc/amazon/efs/efs-utils.conf; fi;
- retryCnt=15; waitTime=30; while true; do mount -a -t efs,nfs4 defaults; if [ $? = 0 ] || [ $retryCnt -lt 1 ]; then echo File system mounted successfully; break; fi; echo File system not available, retrying to mount.; ((retryCnt--)); sleep $waitTime; done;
```

Thank you
Igal

Comment: *How* did you mount the ebs volume, exactly?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's EFS, not EBS

Comment: my apologies! So, how did you mount that exactly, and how do you make sure the growth on the root file system  is not just temporary files or something similar?

Comment: Apologies, I was about to write it here, but hitting "return" key on my computer posted the answer instead of jumping to the next line

Comment: I mounted it based on the AWS documentation, thru the user data

Comment: since the user data is too long for the comment, i posted it here https://pastebin.pl/view/762cc4fe

Comment: @igalsc it would be better to [edit] that as a code block into your question.

Comment: @PhilipCouling thank you, just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like because I am using Ubuntu 22.04LTS, the efs-helper packages from AWS are not working. Also, I was missing the security group permissions to mount the EFS.
Because of this, the `/mnt/efs/fs1` was actually a local to Ubuntu folder.